# Spring Maven - application doesn't start

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I followed a tutorial for developing a spring web mvc application. I also used maven to resolve my dependecies easier but it doesn't seem to work. When i try to run the project, it doesn't go to my index.jsp and if i try to run each page, it also returns me a 404.
Here is my Controller:

```
package com.springmvc.tutorial.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
    String message ="Hello world! Spring !";
    return new ModelAndView("hello","message",message);
}
}
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>SpringMVC9Tutorial</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>spring</display-name>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Here is the spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.springmvc.tutorial.controller">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
</beans>
```

and i have the following structure for my jsps:

```
WEB-INF/index.jsp
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
```

I saw this may be a duplicate question but I couldn't find an answer that satisfied me. I don;t have any errors or exceptions, may just a warning message:

```
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC9Tutorial' did not find a matching property.
```

here is the tutorial; i didn't follwed it exactly:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your servlet context is not initialized properly.Try specifying the servlet in your web.xml

```
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

EDIT : your servelt context naming is matching with servletname , so you dont need to explicitly mention the file. If you have specific name you can specify like above.

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
WEB-INF/index.jsp
```

**You missed a folder for jsp inside WEB-INF as you mentioned in servelt context. But your JSP's are not inside jsp folder.**

**Tell spring to load controllers by annotations like this in your spring-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: yes, it does find spring-servlet.xml/ otherwise it would try me a bunch of exceptions

Comment: i resolved a first part of my problem by moving index.jsp from WEB-INF to to WebContent but now i can;t make neither my link work, neither my servlet load on clicking the link

Comment: and same story: i can't even run the page independently while is located under WEB-INF/jsp folder

Comment: index.jsp is my entry point in the application and i made it work but now i can't get to WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp. I can't get to the servlet for some reason and i didn't miss any folder unfortunely

Comment: Did you try <mvc:annotation-driven/> as mentioned in my answer ?